# Put a comma in a specific column

Tags: awk, sed

I would like to know how to put a comma in one column (space). For example.

```
a b c d e
```

And I would like this.

```
a b c d, e
```

A comma in the 4th space.

I tried with this command.

```
awk -F '{print $4}' < file.txt | cut -d"," -f4-
```

Comment: Do you want to *replace* the space with a comma, or *add* a comma before that space?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{$4=$4","}1' file
a b c d, e
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have only 5 fields(or in case you have more fields in your Input_file and you want to perform this for second last field) in your Input_file then following may also help you in same.

```
awk '{$(NF-1)=$(NF-1)","} 1'  Input_file
```

Or with sed simply replace 4th space with comma as follows.

```
sed 's/ /, /4'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo a b c d e| awk '{$0=gensub(/ /,", ",4)}1'
a b c d, e
```